# Why can't we override `||` and `&&`?

Tags: ruby, keyword

*David A. Black* stated in his book:

> [T]he conditional assignment operator `||=`, as well as its rarely spotted
>   cousin &&=, both of which provide the same kind of shortcut as the pseudooperator methods but are based on operators, namely `||` and `&&`, which you can’t override.

Why did he specifically mention that we can't override `||` and `&&`?

Comment: Because they're part of the language, not methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unlike some other operators on objects, who's behavior logically can depend on class, the boolean operators are part of the language. When you have an operator like, say, `==`, it is logical to say that the behavior of this operator depends on the type of object. A string should check character by character, a Hash key-value tuple by key-value tuple, etc. However, the behavior of `&&` and `||` are based on the *language's* definition of true and false, not anything object specific. If the language allowed you to override these operators, there could be no consistent boolean model, and these operators would become completely useless.

Additionally, there is a performance consideration too. Because `&&` and `||` are *short circut operators*, which means that if the first argument to, say, `&&`, evaluates to false, the second one is never even evaluated. With `||`, if the first evaluates to true, the second is never evaluated. This behavior would not be possible if you could override these operators, as in Ruby operators are overloaded as methods. And all parameters must be evaluated, by definition, before the method is called. So, the performance boost, and programming convenience of a short circuit operator is lost.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to implement lazy evaluation in Ruby (or any language with first-class procedures): just wrap the expression to be lazily evaluated inside a lambda. Ruby *does* have lambdas, even better yet it has *blocks*. It would certainly be possible to implement conditional operators as message sends in Ruby. I actually did that just for fun.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Ture, I never thought of that. Although I'm sure that language level short-circuiting is still more efficient.

Comment: @JörgWMittag If you want to share anything in this context,You can provide here also as an answer. I am eager to see your explanation in my post, what you just said linuxios.

Comment: That's the way it is done in Smalltalk and even mediocre Smalltalk implementations run circles around even the fastest Ruby implementations when it comes to performance. You can do it the same way YARV already does with Fixnum arithmetic: implement them hardcoded in C, but put a guard on them and fallback to normal message dispatch if you detect they are monkey patched.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: True, very true. I think almost all languages run circles around YARV though.