# are Ruby's logical operators methods, like binary operators are?

Tags: ruby

I was wondering, are `&&`, `and`, `||`, `or`  base core unchangeable  functionalities (like in other languages e.g.: php) or are they object methods like `&` `<=>`  but defined some magical way

**More details on my trait of thoughts:**

```
[] & [10]
# => []

[].&([10])
# => []

"aaa".& 10
# NoMethodError: undefined method `&' for "aaa":String
```

note it say undefined **method**

...of course you can do.

```
true.& false
# => false
```

...but you cannot do:

```
true.&& false
# SyntaxError:
```

so If it's possibility to do

```
class String
  # monkey patch. If you googled this don't use this in real world, use ruby mixins insted
  def &(right_side)
    # do something meaningfull
    right_side
  end
end

"aaa".& 10
# => 10     # ta-da!
```

is there (with some magic) possible to do:

```
class String
  # monkey patch. If you googled this don't use this in real world, use ruby mixins insted
  def &&(right side)
    # do something meaningfull
    right side
  end
end
# => SyntaxError: (irb):13: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
```

thx

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't we override \`||\` and \`&&\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311349/why-cant-we-override-and)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the operators that cannot be (re)defined:

- &&, ||  (AND, OR)
- .., ...   (range)
- ?:   (ternary)
- rescue
- =   (and **=, &&=, &=, *=, +=. -=, <<=, >>= , ||=, |=, ^=)
- defined?
- not
- and, or
- if, unless, while, until

The others, like (incomplete list) !, ~, +, -, **, *, /, %, >>, ==, != are implemented as methods and can be redefined.

Comment: `class`, `module` and `def` can be redefined? `raise`?

Comment: @Denis Those are not listed as operators in chapter 4.6 of The Ruby Programming Language. They are keywords however.

Answer (score 2):

*David A. Black* stated in his book:

> [T]he conditional assignment operator `||=`, as well as its rarely spotted
>   cousin &&=, both of which provide the same kind of shortcut as the pseudooperator methods but are based on operators, namely `||` and `&&`, which you can’t override.

Now to get into the reason please Look and read [`Why can't we override`||`and`&&`?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311349/why-cant-we-override-and) and [`Operator Overloading`](http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.com/2010/04/operator-overloading.html).

Comment: thank you for this interesting to read, but I'll have to accept steenslag answer as it's more descriptive.