# || and && aren't methods on Object -- what are they?

Tags: ruby

The single pipe "or"  `|` exists as a method on `TrueClass` and `FalseClass`, but the short circuit `||` operator does not.  Neither does it exist as a method on `Object`.

This seems to be an exception to ruby's "everything is an object" metaphor.

**Main Question:** Syntactically speaking, what *are* `||` and `&&`?  Are they just baked bits of global syntax?

**Secondary Question:** I'm flagging this as not part of the main question, because it is potentially subjective, though I suspect it probably isn't.

Is there a language design or performance reason for this asymmetry?  It seems to me both operators *could have been* implemented as methods on `Object`.  Something like:

```
class Object
  def short_circuit_or(other)
    !nil?       ? true : 
    !other.nil? ? true : false
  end
end
```

I assume there is a reason they were not.  What is it?

Comment: If your `short_circuit_or` is being passed `other` as a value, hasn’t it been evaluated already? That wouldn’t be short-circuiting.

Comment: @Ry- It would be used like `a.short_circuit_or(b)`.  If the value of `a` is non-nil, then it will immediately return `true` and will skip any checks on `b`.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you're getting at... the real short-circuit operator could be used with _expressions_.... whereas this couldn't

Comment: @Jonah with `true || a_very_expensive_operation` you will just get `true`. With `true.short_circuit_or(a_very_expensive_operation)` you will still have to do the evaluation in order to pass it to the `#short_circuit_or` invocation.

Comment: @ndn, yep, i get it now.  That's what I meant by expression, but you're right it could apply to any expensive operation, not just an expensive expression.  although technically speaking even a method call is an expression...

Comment: It _is_ an expression, just a non-short-circuiting one :)

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311349/why-cant-we-override-and). Wouldn't call it a dup though.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo it looks like my guess “baked in bits of syntax” is correct.  The bit about parameters always being evaluated first gets to the heart of the discussion above

Comment: they are part of the syntax called `operators` https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `|` and `||` are [operators](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html). `||` is part of the language while `|` is implemented as a method by some classes ([`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-7C), [`FalseClass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/FalseClass.html#method-i-7C), [`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-7C), [`NilClass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/NilClass.html#method-i-7C) and [`TrueClass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/TrueClass.html#method-i-7C)) .

In programming languages, `|` is used in general as the [bitwise OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) operator. It combines the bits of its integer operands and produces a new integer value. When used with non-integer operands, some languages convert them to integer, others prohibit such usage.

`||` is the [logical OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) operator. It combines two boolean values (`true` or `false`) and produces another boolean value. When its operands are not boolean values, they are converted to boolean by some languages. Ruby (and JavaScript and other languages) evaluate its first operand as boolean and the value of the expression is the value of its first operand if its boolean value is `true` or the value of its second operand if the logical value of its first one is `false`. The type of the resulting value is its original type, it is not converted to boolean.

Each language uses its own rules to decide what non-boolean values are converted to `false` (usually the number `0`, the empty string `''` and `null` or `undefined`); all the other values are converted to `true`. The only "false" values in Ruby are `false` (boolean) and `nil` (non-boolean); all the other values (including `0`) are "true".

Because [`true || anything` is `true`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction#Truth_table) and [`false && anything` is `false`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction#Truth_table), many programming languages including Ruby implement *short-circuit evaluation* for logical expressions.

Using [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), a logical expression is evaluated from left to right, one operand at a time until the value of the expression can be computed without the need to compute the other operands. In the examples above, the value of `anything` doesn't change the value of the entire expression. Using short-circuit evaluation, the value of `anything` is not computed at all because it does not influence the value of the entire expression. Being `anything` a method call that takes considerable time to execute, the short-circuit evaluation avoids calling it and saves execution time.

As others already mentioned in comments to the question, implementing `||` as a method of some class is not possible. The value of its second operand must be evaluated in order to be passed as argument to the method and this breaks the short-circuiting behaviour.

The usual representation of the logical values in programming languages uses only one bit (and I guess Ruby does the same.) Results of `|` and `||` are the same for operands stored on one bit.

Ruby uses the `|` symbol to implement different flavors of the `OR` operation as follows:

- [*bitwise OR*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) for integers;
- non-short-circuit [*logical OR*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) for booleans and `nil`;
- [*union*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) for arrays.

An expression like:

```
x = false | a | b | c
```

ensures that all `a`, `b` and `c` expressions are evaluated (no short-circuit) and the value of `x` is the *logical OR* of the logical values of `a`, `b` and `c`.

If `a`, `b` and `c` are method calls, to achieve the same result using the *logical OR* operator (`||`) the code needs to look like this:

```
aa = a
bb = b
cc = c
x = aa || bb || cc
```

This way each method is called no matter what values are returned by the methods called before it.

For [`TrueClass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/TrueClass.html#method-i-7C), [`FalseClass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/FalseClass.html#method-i-7C) and [`NilClass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/NilClass.html#method-i-7C), the `|` operator is useful when short-circuit evaluation is not desired.

Also, for [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-7C) (an array is just an ordered set), the `|` operator implements union, an operation that is the semantically equivalent of *logical OR* for sets.

Comment: I rephrased the explanation of the example code and corrected (I hope) the other errors.

Comment: Much better now :)